# How to create an auto-complete search in Ajax and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating a basic autocomplete ajax script to fetch the mysql database search results but am unable to display the results in the php page.

I can see the data getting fetched from the database in search.php as an array, but the same doesn't get displayed in the check.php page. Is this something because of some kind of css, or some other issue?

Any suggestions would be of great help!!

Here is the code >

**check.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

    li.ui-menu-item{
        font-size: 12px !important;
    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#regionsearch').autocomplete({
            source: 'search.php',
            minLength:1
        });
    });

</script> 


</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="POST">
    Search: <input type="text" name="search" id="regionsearch"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php


$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('user_information');


if(isset($_REQUEST['term']))
    exit();




$rs = mysql_query('Select * from registered_users where first_name like "'.ucfirst($_REQUEST['term']).'%" order by id asc limit 0,10',
    $dblink);

$data = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $data[] = array(
            'label'=>$row['first_name'],
            'value'=>$row['first_name']
        );
}

echo json_encode($data);
flush()

?>
```

Comment: when i type the required alphabet, it says 'No search results'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since you are using a jquery ui plugin, you will need to embed the appropriate css.

To follow what you've already done, use this line in your html template :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
```

You should as well se the doc to fetch remote data and adapt your code :

> https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#regionsearch').autocomplete({
        source: 'search.php',
        minLength:1,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            q: request.term
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i added this, now it does not display anything, the data gets fetched in the search.php though as usual but nothing now in check.php

Comment: You should check the documentation here to see how to fetch data from a remote source : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: Do you fetch any data from the db ? what do you get on the success return ? Do you got some errors in the console ? Can you check the servor response when search.php is called ?

Comment: so, if i run search.php separately, it returns the db data like this :  [{"label":"d","value":"d"},{"label":"a","value":"a"},{"label":"f","value":"f"},{"label":"d","value":"d"}].    the values here are appearing correct from the db